# How to create .Deb pkg such that it should has access read write permission in /opt/myprogram

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu-16.04, deb, folder-permissions

I'm developing application that is installing in /opt folder. My application fetches .zip file and tries to write in /opt/myprogram/ but it is failing due to permission issues.
If I run as root it will work.
So how can I create Deb package such that it has full read and write permission for that user under /opt/myprogram

Comment: What do you mean by "that user"? The program will run with the privileges of whoever invokes it, so you seem to be asking how to make a system directory world-writable, which obviously is not good practice.

Comment: A good workaround might be to have a simple downloader component which runs once when you install the package, and then periodically from a system crontab as root.

Comment: "That user" running user